# SharePoint 2013 REST API GetItems in all site collection

Tags: rest, sharepoint

I use this POST request for get items

```
var url="/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('Documents')/GetItems(query=@v1)?$select=Title,FileRef&@v1={\"ViewXml\":\"<View><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef%20Name='societe'/><Value%20Type='TaxonomyFieldType'>"+currentCompany+"</Value></Eq></Where></Query></View>\"}";
       console.log(url);
        return $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: "/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('Documents')/GetItems(query=@v1)?$select=Title,FileRef&@v1={\"ViewXml\":\"<View><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef%20Name='societe'/><Value%20Type='TaxonomyFieldType'>"+currentCompany+"</Value></Eq></Where></Query></View>\"}",
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json;odata=verbose'
                , 'X-RequestDigest': $('#__REQUESTDIGEST').val()
            }
        });
```

That works but I would like to get this items in all site collection and not just in Documents List.

Is it possible ?

Comment: I cant use GET request because I need to make filter on a TaxonomyField

Answer (score 0):

There is something called SPSiteDataQuery in the Server Side Object Model which allows to query for content across the whole site collection - if you work in OnPrem, you might be able to utilize that. Unfortunately, there is no equivalent for this functionality on the client side (so in JSOM, CSOM and REST).

However, depending on your use case you can might consider using SharePoint Search. Keep in mind, though, that it might not return the results you want and that changes made to the items will not be instantly visible in the results (it might even take a couple of hours for the index to be updated).

More on SPSiteDataQuery: [SPSiteDataQuery Share Point Example](https://sureshunakka87.wordpress.com/2014/10/02/spsitedataquery-share-point-example/)

Linked thread on SharePoint Stack Exchange: [Can we use SPSiteDataQuery in JSOM OUT OF BOX?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/239804/can-we-use-spsitedataquery-in-jsom-out-of-box)

More about Search: [Using the SharePoint search Query APIs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/using-the-sharepoint-search-query-apis)

Comment: Thanks but I need a client side solution

Comment: In that case, as I mentioned: SharePoint Search is probably your only option